# Как мне подключить два сайта в одном домене?

Tags: nginx

Я пробовал такой конфиг сделать, то есть начальная страница это лендинг, а под admin там уже стоит laravel c фронтендом и бекендом. Это идет как отдельное приложение не зависимое от лендинга, ну может немного, только запись из базы данных может быть зависет, но там только запись одного запроса.
Я сделал вот такой конфиг **/etc/nginx/sites-available/latina**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /home/ruslan/Разработка/latina;
  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  server_name latina.site www.latina.site;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
  }


  location /admin {
    root    /home/ruslan/Разработка/latina/admin/public;
    index   index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

ТО есть лендинг все замечательно работает, а вот директория latina.site/admin Выходит 404 ошибка
В **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
  worker_connections 4096;
  multi_accept on;
}

http {

  ##
  # Basic Settings
  ##

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  client_max_body_size 100M;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;

   server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  ##
  # SSL Settings
  ##

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  ##
  # Logging Settings
  ##

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  ##
  # Gzip Settings
  ##

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";

  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

При этом синтаксических ошибок нет

```
uslan@debian:~$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

и перезагружается nginx все нормально
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А замена "location /admin" на "location /admin/" ничего не меняет? Сейчас проверю поточнее.

Comment: Имеется ли симлинк на sites-available/latina в sites-enabled?

Comment: да, имеется. На нем лендинг работает, а там идет через php отправка email еще

Comment: Я просто добавил туда location /admin

Comment: На что location /admin/, то все равно не работает

Comment: ruslan@debian:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ ls
latina

Comment: В location /admin замените `root` на `alias`

Comment: @andreymal не помогло

Comment: ваша 404 из бекенда или из nginx? мне кажется, что запрос доходит до бека и именно он отвечает 404той

Comment: Лог посмотрите, скорее всего у вас неверная кодировка файла конфигурации, и русские символы не правильно читаются.

Comment: `root    /home/ruslan/Разработка/latina/admin/public;` => `alias    /home/ruslan/Разработка/latina/` (или с admin/public/ в конце попробовать) а если root то `root    /home/ruslan/Разработка/latina`

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
location /admin/ {
    root /home/ruslan/Разработка/latina/admin/public;
    index   index.html index.htm index.php;
}
```

Учтите, что в этой конфигурации при обращении к /admin/ будет производиться поиск файлов-индексов в `/home/ruslan/Разработка/latina/admin/public/admin/`, а обращение к /admin будет давать 404.

Comment: что то тоже не помогло

Comment: То есть если у меня index.php находиться под этому пути /home/ruslan/Разработка/latina/admin/public/index.php То мне нужно location изменить или не совсем понял? просто там появилось /admin/